# Beamer presentation: manually control the header text in Dresden theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer, presentations

Is there a way to manually control the text that will be printed in the header, when using the `\usetheme{Dresden}` of `\documentclass{beamer}`? I noticed that this text is controlled by the strings placed in the:

```
\section{Introduction}

\section{Chapter 1: Asymptotic Single Risk Factor Models with Stochastic and Correlated LGD}

\section{Chapter 2: Multi-Factor Extensions to the Asymptotic Single Risk Factor Models}

\section{Chapter 3: Non-Gaussian Copulas Extensions to the Asymptotic Single Risk Factor Model}

\section{Conclusion}
```

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the text present in the `\section{}`  is too long and goes beyond the header space ...

To be very specific, I would like to keep using these section titles, but be able to manually control the text printed in the header, e.g. Introduction, Chapter 1, Chapter 2, Chapter 3, Planning (would be a good sequence).

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the optional argument to `\section`:

```
\section{Introduction}

\section[Chapter 1]{Chapter 1: Asymptotic Single Risk Factor Models with Stochastic and Correlated LGD}

\section[Chapter 2]{Chapter 2: Multi-Factor Extensions to the Asymptotic Single Risk Factor Models}

\section[Chapter 3]{Chapter 3: Non-Gaussian Copulas Extensions to the Asymptotic Single Risk Factor Model}

\section{Conclusion}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much for the input!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have been able to help!